# Adding require cause PHPUnit to report Restricted Area

Tags: php, phpunit

I wrote a unit test for one of my class and when i add in a require file, it reported restricted area. what does it mean? how should i properly import a php class file for unit testing?

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying to test, and the test case?

Comment: Show your code and full error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why. On the top of each class there is this line

defined('RISTO') or die('Restricted Area');